# Seaborn time series plotting: a different problem for each function

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to use seaborn dataframe functionality (e.g. passing column names to `x`, `y` and `hue` plot parameters) for my timeseries (in pandas datetime format) plots.

- `x` should come from a timeseries column(converted from a pd.Series of strings with pd.to_datetime)
- `y` should come from a float column
- `hue` comes from a categorical column that I calculated.

There are multiple streams in the same series that I am trying to separate (and use the hue for separating them visually), and therefore they should not be connected by a line (like in a scatterplot)

I have tried the following plot types, each with a different problem:

- `sns.scatterplot`: gets the plotting right and the labels right bus has problems with the xlimits, and I could not set them right with plt.xlim() using data.Dates.min and data.Dates.min
- `sns.lineplot`: gets the limits and the labels right but I could not find a setting to disable the lines between the individual datapoints like in matplotlib. I tried the setting the `markers` and the `dashes` parameters to no avail.
- `sns.stripplot`: my last try, plotted the datapoints correctly and got the xlimits right but messed the labels ticks

Example input data for easy reproduction:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(('2017-11-15',
    '2017-11-29',
    '2017-12-15',
    '2017-12-28',
    '2018-01-15',
    '2018-01-30',
    '2018-02-15',
    '2018-02-27',
    '2018-03-15',
    '2018-03-27',
    '2018-04-13',
    '2018-04-27',
    '2018-05-15',
    '2018-05-28',
    '2018-06-15',
    '2018-06-28',
    '2018-07-13',
    '2018-07-27'))
values = np.random.randn(len(dates))
clusters = np.random.randint(1, size=len(dates))
D = {'Dates': dates, 'Values': values, 'Clusters': clusters}
data = pd.DataFrame(D)
```

To each of the functions I am passing the same arguments:

```py
sns.OneOfThePlottingFunctions(x='Dates',
                     y='Values',
                     hue='Clusters',
                     data=data)
plt.show()
```

So to recap, what I want is a plot that uses seaborn's pandas functionality, and plots points(not lines) with correct x limits and readable x labels :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using a`scatterplot` and `plt.xlim(data.Dates.min(), data.Dates.max())`  results in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv10L.png). This seems fine though. Is the problem that the first and last point are partially cropped? For a `lineplot` adding `marker="o", linewidth=0` should also give the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='Dates', y='Values', hue='Clusters', data=data)
ax.set_xlim(data['Dates'].min(), data['Dates'].max())
```